# Llamar desde javascript a un evento creado en un ascx con valor null y donde se define este evento en la pagina donde se añade el ascx

Tags: javascript, aspx, usercontrol

Tengo un control de usuario llamado **miControlUsuario.ascx** en este se configuró un evento publico en el archivo **miControlUsuario.ascx.cs** se ha llamado a este evento **miEvento** y para crearlo lo he configurado del siguiente modo:

```
public event EventHandler miEvento;
```

Actualmente lo que hago es en **miControlUsuario.ascx.cs** llamar al evento desde algún método dentro de este control

```
miEvento(null, null);
```

Hay que definirlo en la pagína web o archivo *.aspx.cs este evento en para ser ejecutado según la configuración deseada por el usuario que añade el control a su pagina

```
protected void miEvento(object sender, eventargs e)
{

}
```

¿Cómo hago desde el archivo **miControlUsuario.ascx** con javaScript llamar al evento que debe estar configurado en el **page** donde se ha agregado mi control de usuario y así ejecutar su definición?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!